# How to change base choice in OrderingFilter from django-filter?

Tags: python, django, filter, django-filter

I have such filter and i'd like to do one of these things:

1. Change -------- to other label
2. Remove --------
3. Set From cheaper to expensive as a base choice and remove ---------

[image]

My filter:

```
class OrderFilter(FilterSet):
sort_by_price = django_filters.OrderingFilter(
    # model field name: parameter name
    fields=('price', 'price'),
    # change basic labels of the filter choices
    field_labels = {
        'price': 'From cheaper to expensive',
        '-price': 'From expensive to cheaper'
    },
    label='Order'
)

class Meta:
    model = Item
    fields = ""
```

Comment: Can you please share your Django filter you are using right now?

Comment: Yes, of course, check my edit

Comment: what if you specify `requred=True` in your `OrderingFilter`?

Comment: It sets From cheaper to expensive as a default choice, but ------ still exists